# Generar una tabla semanal de concurrencia de usuarios por dia

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Tengo esta tabla creada en mariadb

```
CREATE TABLE usuario_plan_inscripcion (
 id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 dia INT NOT NULL,
 inicio TIME NOT NULL,
 fin TIME NOT NULL,
 usuarioPerfilId INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Con este tipo de registros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces quiero lograr algo como esto, los datos que puse, son meramente representativos

```
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| hora     | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  | 6  |
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 6:00:00  | 12 | 12 | 12 | 23 | 32 | 67 | 97 |
| 7:00:00  | 12 | 12 | 12 | 23 | 32 | 67 | 97 |
| 8:00:00  | 12 | 12 | 12 | 23 | 32 | 67 | 97 |
| 9:00:00  | 12 | 12 | 12 | 23 | 32 | 67 | 97 | 
| 10:00:00 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 23 | 32 | 67 | 97 |
| 11:00:00 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 23 | 32 | 67 | 97 |
| 12:00:00 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 23 | 32 | 67 | 97 |
| 13:00:00 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 23 | 32 | 67 | 97 |
| 14:00:00 | 12 | 12 | 12 | 23 | 32 | 67 | 97 |
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

No he podido lograrlo, tampoco sé si sea posible con la actual estructura de mi tabla. Podrían orientarme para poder lograrlo, si es necesario modificar la tabla también podría hacerlo.